# user table data updated ,but not reflected in AuthorizationServerProvider's "GrantResourceOwnerCredentials" methord

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2, owin, autofac, dispose

Basically I deleted a user from user table, after that logging in using the same user credentials is happening.In short the Database changes is not being reflected in owin authentication.

Note : I am using Deleting user is actually updating the "Deletedon" field in user table. And also am using Custom Data Context in Owin.

After Restarting IIS it works fine.Pls Help!!.

here is my ConfigureOAuth methord inside startup class:

```cs
public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
    var authService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IAuthService>();
    var userService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IUserService>();
    var loginHistoryService = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<ILoginHistoryService>();
    //use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
    OAuthBearerOptions = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions();
    OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
    {
        AllowInsecureHttp = true,
        TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
        AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
        Provider = new AuthorizationServerProvider(authService, userService, loginHistoryService),
        RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider(authService)
    };
    // Token Generation
    app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
    app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(OAuthBearerOptions);
}
```

here is my AuthorizationServerProvider class:

```cs
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    var allowedOrigin = context.OwinContext.Get<string>("as:clientAllowedOrigin");

    if (allowedOrigin == null) allowedOrigin = "*";

    context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { allowedOrigin });

    var user = await _authService.ValidateUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
    if (user == false)
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
        return;
    }


    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.UserName));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Client"));
    identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));

    var userInformation = await _userService.GetUserDetails(context.UserName, context.Password);
    if (userInformation != null)
    {
        /*insertion to login history*/

        _loginHistoryService.Create(userInformation.Id);

    }
    var props = new AuthenticationProperties(new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            {
                "as:client_id", (context.ClientId == null) ? string.Empty : context.ClientId
            },
            {
                "userName", context.UserName
            },

            {
                "UserId", userInformation.Id.ToString()
            },
             {
                "BranchId", userInformation.BranchId.ToString()
            },
             {
                "Name", userInformation.Name.ToString()
            }

        });

    var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(identity, props);
    context.Validated(ticket);
}
```

`_authService.ValidateUser` gives old(not updated) user data.

Comment: does your implementation of `IAuthService` somehow caches the result of credentials validation? It's important for you to understand that the way it is configured, you effectively have single instances of `IAuthService`, `IUserService` and `ILoginHistoryService` for the life of the application.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion ...I got my answer by adding ".AsNoTracking() "in my query.    (_context.Users.AsNoTracking())....